# In JavaFx, how to get parameters from timeline?

Tags: java, javafx

I create a code using `timeline` to implement a crawl effect.

Now I would like to use `KeyEvent` to add pause and reverse function. The pause function can be accomplished using `timeline.pause();` but for reverse function, I need to get two parameters. My codes for the timeline:

```
Timeline tl = new Timeline();
        tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame moveText = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.0400),
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    double a,b;
                    a=0.9;
                    b = 0.5*(1-0.99)*a;
                    shiftAndScale(group, b, upperStep, 0.99, 0.99);
                      }
                });
        tl.getKeyFrames().add(moveText);
        tl.play();
```

Then I add the `KeyEvent` to pause and reverse:

```
scene.onKeyPressedProperty().set(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {

                if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    tl.pause();
                }
                if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                    // reverse function, but requires the current a and b;
                }
            }
        });
```

Therefore, when I pause the timeline, how to let the program return the variables a and b?

Comment: Why do you want it to be deleted? The question and its answer can be helpful for other users. Why not to collaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make double a and b a field or set it into another variable accessible to KeyEvent